# Map of collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

I wanted to make Map of Collections in Java, so I can make something like

```
public void add(K key, V value) {  
    if (containsKey(key)) {
        get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        Collection c = new Collection();
        c.add(value);
        put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I've tried to make it with something like

```
public class CollectionMap<K, C extends Collection<V>> extends HashMap<K, C>
```

but compiler complains about the `<V>` part, and there would still be an issue of making proper new collection.

At the moment, I've made two classes: SetMap that look like this

```
 1: public class SetMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, Set<V>> {
 2: 
 3:    public void add(K key, V value) {
 4:        if (containsKey(key)) {
 5:            get(key).add(value);
 6:        } else {
 7:            Set<V> list = new HashSet<V>();
 8:            list.add(value);
 9:            put(key, list);
10:        }
11:    }
12:
13: }
```

and ListMap looks pretty much the same except the line 7 where I make new ArrayList. This sort of duplication is small enough to be tolerable, but question remains is this sort of "nested generics" possible in Java?

EDIT:

As [erickson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254351/map-of-collections#254372), solution is in `<A, B extends Something<A>>` rather than just `<B extends Something<A>>`

so code can look something like

```
public abstract class CollelctionMap<K, V, C extends Collection<V>> extends HashMap<K, C> {

    protected abstract C newCollection();

    public void add(K key, V value) {
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            C c = newCollection();
            c.add(value);
            put(key, c);
        }
    }
}
```

and ListMap and SetMap only provide proper collection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `map` is a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, use the idiom [`computeIfAbsent(...).add(...)`,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) like this:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Or, for a `Set`:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's an option, you may want to just use the Google Collections API - http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/.

Even if you can't use it, maybe having a look at how they implemented their MultiMaps would help you with your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your code:

Collection c = new Collection();

Cannot be instantiated.

I think the next piece of code will solve your problem:

```
public class CollectionMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, Collection<V>> {


    ...
    ...
    ...


    public void add(K key, V value) {
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            Collection<V> c = new ArrayList<V>();
            c.add(value);
            super.put(key, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I've mentioned that, it is just there to ilustrate an idea

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Collections also offers a MultiMap, but it's pre-JDK 1-.5, so you'll have no generics safety there. You can wrap it in a Collections.checkedMap(Key.class, Value.class, collection) for run-time safety. If you can use Google's Colelction API, it offers an even slicker MultiMap with all the generics, bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2):

If possible use Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).  Guys have done a wonderful job there.

Here is another solution.

```
abstract class MultiMap<K, V> {

    private Map<K, Collection<V>> entries = new LinkedHashMap<K, Collection<V>>();

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        Collection<V> values = entries.get(key);
        if (values == null) {
            entries.put(key, values = newValueCollection());
        }
        values.add(value);
    }

    // other methods
    // ..

    abstract Collection<V> newValueCollection();



    // Helper methods to create different flavors of MultiMaps

    public static <K, V> MultiMap<K, V> newArrayListMultiMap() {
        return new MultiMap<K, V>() {
            Collection<V> newValueCollection() {
                return new ArrayList<V>();
            }
        };
    }

    public static <K, V> MultiMap<K, V> newHashSetMultiMap() {
        return new MultiMap<K, V>() {
            Collection<V> newValueCollection() {
                return new HashSet<V>();
            }
        };
        }

 }
```

You can use it like

```
MultiMap<String, Integer> data = MultiMap.newArrayListMultiMap();
data.put("first", 1);
data.put("first", 2);
data.put("first", 3);
```