# Java: add to map of collections

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to write a generic function that will add an element to a `Map` of `Collection`s. This works for a `Map` of `List`s:

```
public static <TKey, TVal> void addToMapOfLists(Map<TKey, List<TVal>> map, TKey key, TVal val) {
    List<TVal> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(val);
        map.put(key, list);
    } else
        list.add(val);
}
```

I want to make this function work on `Map<TKey, Set<TVal>>` as well as on `Map<TKey, List<TVal>>`. I expect this should be possible because both implement `Collection` that has the `add(TVal)` member that I call.

My problem is that when I try change the parameter `Map<TKey, List<TVal>> map` to `Map<TKey, ? extends Collection<TVal>> map` - I need to somehow replace `new ArrayList<>();` with a call to the constructor of the implementer of `Collection`.

Comment: How you chose to use a List or a Set ? By reflection in java you can't find what is the generic type of the parameter Map at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254351/map-of-collections

Comment: Obviously (coming from C++) - list or set is chosen depending on the type of map. The default ctor is called for either.

Comment: @AnkitTripathi, I looked at that question before asking this one. That question asks about defining a new type and this asks about adding to an existing map. The answers are also not very useful for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to pass an additional parameter to your method - a `Supplier` of `Collection` instances.

Here's one possible implementation :

```
public static <TKey, TVal, TCol extends Collection<TVal>> void addToMapOfCollections(Map<TKey, Collection<TVal>> map, TKey key, TVal val, Supplier<TCol> supplier) 
{
    Collection<TVal> col = map.get(key);
    if (col == null) {
        col = supplier.get ();
        col.add(val);
        map.put(key, col);
    } else {
        col.add(val);
    }
}
```

Here's another option :

```
public static <TKey, TVal> void addToMapOfCollections(Map<TKey, Collection<TVal>> map, TKey key, TVal val, Supplier<Collection<TVal>> supplier)
{
    Collection<TVal> col = map.get(key);
    if (col == null) {
        col = supplier.get ();
        col.add(val);
        map.put(key, col);
    } else {
        col.add(val);
    }
}
```

And with less code (as suggested by Gerald) :

```
public static <TKey, TVal> void addToMapOfCollections(Map<TKey, Collection<TVal>> map, TKey key, TVal val, Supplier<Collection<TVal>> supplier)
{
    map.putIfAbsent(key, supplier.get());
    map.get(key).add(val);
}
```

I tested the second variant :

```
Map<String,Collection<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
addToMapOfCollections(map,"String1",5,HashSet::new);
addToMapOfCollections(map,"String2",67,ArrayList::new);
addToMapOfCollections(map,"String2",68,ArrayList::new);
System.out.println (map);
for (Collection<Integer> col : map.values ()) {
    System.out.println (col.getClass () + " : " + col);
}
```

Output :

```
{String2=[67, 68], String1=[5]}
class java.util.ArrayList : [67, 68]
class java.util.HashSet : [5]
```

Comment: one additional simplification could be made to the method by using `putIfAbsent` to initialize the collection: `map.putIfAbsent(key, supplier.get()); map.get(key).add(value)`

Comment: @GeraldMücke Good suggestion.